# CovertFlow apple code example

Tags: cocoa

Apple was providing with previous versions of XCode an code example nammed CovertFlow.
Unfortunately , it is no more provided with the current version.

I am looking for this sample, do you know where I can find a copy?

Answer (score 1):

Erica Sadun has a cover flow type code sample for the iPhone. You can download that at her site.